# How can I connect to RabbitMQ using Sockjs and Stomp in React?

Tags: reactjs, rabbitmq, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to connect to RabbitMQ using Stomp and Sockjs. I have Stomp.js and Sock.js files. I have already tried 'react-load-script' module to load the scripts but they seem to run into scope issues. Is there any other way to do this? I tried using 'react-stomp' as well and it runs into CORS issue and when that resolves, application refuses to connect to Stomp url. Is there any other way to do this?